# Is it good practice to use a break statement in this js code snippet?

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, refactoring

The purpose of this function is to calculate a price (result) based on a given airline rate table (param 1) and a weight (param 2). The array line in the rates array signify: [weight break, rate/kg, breakpoint].

Example of the calculation:

- check if given weight is below the weight break (`wb`), apply the minimum rate, which is the `wb * rate`;

- if not, check if the weight is below the breakpoint (`bp`), calculate the `weight * rate`;
- if the weight is higher than the `bp`, apply the `wb` of the next array times the rate of the next array.

Note: the last line in the rates table does not have a `bp`. That's simply how these tables are provided.

TLDR:

My code works just fine (see below), but I am very new at this and I wonder if there is a better way to write this little algorithm. I spot recursion, but I am not sure how to write a recursive function. Perhaps this can be written in a more concise way? I am asking the question to get better at coding. Thanks!

```
rates = [
    [ 45, 3.8, 88 ],
    [ 100, 3.35, 296 ],
    [ 300, 3.3, 492 ],
    [ 500, 3.25]
];

function calcPrice(arr, weight) {
    let price = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (weight <= arr[i][0]) {
            price = arr[i][0] * arr[i][1]; break;
        } else if (weight <= arr[i][2] && arr[i][2] !== undefined) {
            price = weight * arr[i][1]; break;
        } else {
            price = weight * arr[i][1];
        }
    }
    return price;
}
console.log(calcPrice(rates, 89);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tagged with [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recursion/info), and I think that's a useful call.  A recursive version of this function using destructuring and default parameters ends up being quite simple:

```js
const calcPrice = ([[wb, rate, bp = Infinity], ...rates], weight = 0) =>
  weight < bp 
    ? rate * Math .max (wb, weight) 
    : calcPrice (rates, weight);

const rates = [[45, 3.8, 88], [100, 3.35, 296], [300, 3.3, 492], [500, 3.25]];

const vals = [33, 47, 85, 90, 103, 296, 297, 302, 490, 497, 2001]
vals .forEach (v => console .log (`${v} : ${calcPrice(rates, v).toFixed(2)}`))
```

Note that by defaulting the breakpoint to `Infinity`, we can avoid any special checking for the existence of a third entry.  Also, the logic about how to do the actual calculation is simplified by noting that we have to compare only with the breakpoint, using a `max` to choose the value to multiply with our rate.  So if the weight is less than the breakpoint, we can return `rate * Math .max (wb, weight)`.  If it's not, then we recur on the remaining elements of our array.

Also, your title asked about the use of the `break` statement.  I think your instinct is correct; these should be quite rare.  They usually point to code that might do well with a serious refactoring.  Besides the recursive technique above, you could also manage this by using something like `const [wp, rate, bp = Infinity] = rates.find(([ , , bp]) => weight <= bp)`.  That would also avoid the `break` statements as well as the explicit `for`-loop.

### Update

This version carries a lot more error-correction by a careful use of default parameters:

```js
const calcPrice = (
  [[weightbreak = 0, rate = 0, breakpoint = Infinity] = [0, 0, Infinity], ...rates] = [], 
  weight = 0
) =>
  weight < breakpoint
    ? rate * Math .max (weightbreak, weight) 
    : calcPrice (rates, weight);
```

It won't throw an error if the array of `rates` doesn't exist, or if it's empty, or if some of the values are missing.  Instead, it will return zero in most of those circumstances.  And it will handle any `weight`, again using the `Infinity` to capture large values not yet matched.

Comment: Thank you Scott. This is very helpful for my learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple ways you could make this more concise and readable. It's really just a couple small things.

First one is a JavaScript trick called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). This would allow you to give variable names to the values in the arrays like this:

```js
const [weightBreak, rate, breakpoint] = arr[i];
```

Then this: `arr[i][0] * arr[i][1]` becomes `weightBreak * rate`.

Another small thing is formatting (could just be having to type it into this site). Even if it seems minor, properly formatting your code goes a long way for readability.

Last thing: it looks like that else block could be called on every iteration if we don't find any items in `arr` where `weight <= arr[i][0]` or `weight <= arr[i][2]`. In that case, what we're returning is a value based on the last item in `arr`. If we use early `return` statements instead of `break` statements, we could pull that part out of the loop entirely.

If we put all that together, then we get:

```js
function calcPrice(arr, weight) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const [weightBreak, rate, breakpoint] = arr[i];

    if (weight <= weightBreak) {
      return weightBreak * rate;
    }

    if (weight <= breakpoint && breakpoint !== undefined) {
      return weight * rate;
    }
  }

  const lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
  return weight * lastItem[1];
}
```

If you'd like me to clarify any of these, please feel free to ask! I hope that helps and happy coding!

Comment: Oh wow, I was aware of the concept of destructuring assignment, but I did not realize I could apply it to the positions in my array. But it makes a lot of sense. The code is much more readable like this. Thanks a lot.
One verification. You have removed the else-statement. Is it my understanding that in the for-loop there weren't any TRUE evaluations, so the program moves on and hits the last return, which multiplies the weight times the lastItem?

Comment: That's correct. :)
I did that because that's essentially what's happening in the code in your question. The else block was getting evaluated on every loop, but only the last value ever gets returned.

Comment: That's right! It makes sense to do it that way. Thanks, I have learned a few things this morning. This is the first time I am trying to type something useful. Making a custom function to be used in Google Sheets. :-). Going through arrays one by was a headache mainly because of my notation ;-). Your cleanup looks a lot more like the pseudo-code  I wrote in preparation for this :-). Thanks, have a great day!

Comment: For anybody interested in a good article on destructuring: https://thenextweb.com/syndication/2020/07/25/how-to-write-cleaner-code-with-javascript/